# Show error toaster message on window.open function

Tags: javascript, html

While using `window.open(url, _self)` I want show some toaster error message if url is invalid.
I tried window error events but no luck.
I dont want to use jQuery ajax for checking if file is available and again making a call using window.open function.

Comment: What's wrong with the checking ajax call ?

Comment: I dont want to make multiple call, one ajax call and one window.open to open a page.